# Using RxJS combineLatest to filter observables?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, stackblitz

I'm seeing if I can use `combineLatest` within an Angular service to remove the `activeFiler$` switch block (The service should be doing the same thing).  This is the component [design right now (stackblitz link)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/slice-todo-hacking?file=src/app/todos.component.ts) and I'm trying to remove all the properties except for the `render$` observable:

```
export class TodosComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private ts:TodoService) {}
  render$: Observable<Todo[]>; 
  activeFilter$: Observable<VISIBILITY_FILTER>;


ngOnInit() {
  this.render$ = this.ts.selectedTodos$;
  this.activeFilter$ = this.ts.activeFilter$;

  this.activeFilter$.subscribe(active=>{
        switch (active) {
    case VISIBILITY_FILTER.SHOW_COMPLETED:
      this.render$ = this.ts.completeTodos$;
      break;
    case VISIBILITY_FILTER.SHOW_ACTIVE:
      this.render$ = this.ts.incompleteTodos$;
      break;
    default:
      this.render$ = this.ts.todos$;
      }
  });
}
  }
}
```

As shown I have initialized `this.render$` to an Observable returned from the `todo.service.ts` file.  The method looks like this:

```
  this.selectedTodos$ = 
  combineLatest(this.activeFilter$, this.completeTodos$, this.incompleteTodos$, this.todos$, this.applyFilter);

  private applyFilter(filter, completeTodos, incompleteTodos, todos): Todo[] {
    switch (filter) {
      case VISIBILITY_FILTER.SHOW_COMPLETED:
        return completeTodos;
      case VISIBILITY_FILTER.SHOW_ACTIVE:
        return incompleteTodos;
      default:
        return todos;
    }
  }
```

So with all that in place, I think I should be able to remove the `this.ts.ostore.observe(ACTIVE_FILTER_KEY).subscribe(active=>{`
 block in the todos component, but if I removed that the whole app stops working.

One strange thing is that if I comment out the `$activeFilter` subscription, and log this:

```
  this.render$ = this.ts.selectedTodos$;
  this.render$.subscribe(v=>console.log(v));
```

When I enter more todos, they get logged, but they don't render ... Any ideas?

Comment: What's `completeLatest`?

Comment: Sorry - combineLatest - https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Comment: The code inside ngOnInit is not proper RxJS. Changing `this.render$` has no effect on subscribers. I think what your really need is  switchMap.

Comment: @edwin I think the issue is that `combineLatest` will not emit anything until all the `Subject` instances being observed emit at least one value.  In my case I'm using it to filter `COMPLETE`, `INCOMPLETE`, and `ALL` but the `COMPLETE` subject never gets any values to emit, so it never fires, and `combineLatest` just sits there and waits for it.  I'm updating the store implementation to emit an empty array on construction, so that `combineLatests` is guaranteed a value from each Observable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

The core part that makes it work is that `combineLatest` emits when each `Observable` emits AT LEAST once.

In my case the `ReplaySubject<Todo[]>` instances that performed notifications did not perform a notification when the [EStore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/slice) was initialized, and therefore the `ReplaySubject<Todo[]>`s could never fire the `combinedLatest` operator.

I changed the [EStore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/slice) implementation such that it does emit nothing or the entities that the `EStore` was initialized with, and now it works...really well.

```
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
```

Works.  We don't need event emitters or `@Input` for it to work.  Just query the store and let it do its magic.